# mysql limit with in clause

Tags: mysql, limit, where-clause

```
SELECT *
FROM restaurant_rate
WHERE 
    table_id IN (SELECT id_table FROM rTable WHERE restaurant_id = ?)
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

The number of the result of the inner select is not static. In this case, mysql scans only 10 rows searching one by one? Or scans whole table and returns top 10 rows? 
The id_table is an index column of rTable.

Comment: You may need an index for `restaurant_id` as well in `id_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your query is written is quite inneficient, because it forces to evaluate the `in` clause *for every row* in your table. If there are many records in `rTable` that match the criteria (let's say 1000), every row in `restaurant_rate` will need to be compared with 1000 values before being accepted or rejected by the `where` condition.

I would rewrite your query like this:

```
select rr.*
from 
    restaurant_rate as rr
    inner join rTAble as r on rr.table_id = r.id_table
where
    r.restaurant_id = ?
limit 0, 10;
```

Things you must consider:

- You **need** indexes for the columns involved in the `join` and in the `where` condition.
- Using `limit` without `order by` does not makes much sense; add an `order by` clause before the `limit`.

Comment: Thanks Barranka. Your answer "it forces to evaluate the in clause for every row in your table" is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.